# Getting [GridDhtAtomicCache] Unexpected exception during cache update java.lang.NullPointerException in Ignite cluster deployed in AKS

Tags: azure-aks, ignite

we have deployed Ignite cluster on AKS, and using the Transformer application which will initialize the cache in Ignite cluster. we are getting the following exception.

```
[08:18:14,437][SEVERE][sys-stripe-2-#3][GridDhtAtomicCache] <osdu_wks_master-data--SeismicAcquisitionSurvey_1.0.0> Unexpected exception during cache update
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.locationtech.jts.io.WKTWriter.appendCoordinate(WKTWriter.java:529)
        at org.locationtech.jts.io.WKTWriter.appendLineStringText(WKTWriter.java:602)
        at org.locationtech.jts.io.WKTWriter.appendMultiLineStringText(WKTWriter.java:685)
        at org.locationtech.jts.io.WKTWriter.appendMultiLineStringTaggedText(WKTWriter.java:444)
        at org.locationtech.jts.io.WKTWriter.appendGeometryTaggedText(WKTWriter.java:345)
        at org.locationtech.jts.io.WKTWriter.writeFormatted(WKTWriter.java:312)
        at org.locationtech.jts.io.WKTWriter.write(WKTWriter.java:253)
        at org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry.toText(Geometry.java:1161)
        at org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry.toString(Geometry.java:1149)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
        at org.gridgain.internal.h2.value.ValueGeometry.getFromGeometry(ValueGeometry.java:101)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2Utils.wrap(H2Utils.java:676)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.H2CacheRow.wrap(H2CacheRow.java:183)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.H2CacheRow.getValue0(H2CacheRow.java:118)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.H2CacheRow.getValue(H2CacheRow.java:100)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2SpatialIndex.getEnvelope(GridH2SpatialIndex.java:229)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2SpatialIndex.put(GridH2SpatialIndex.java:204)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2SpatialIndex.putx(GridH2SpatialIndex.java:218)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table.addToIndex(GridH2Table.java:934)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table.update(GridH2Table.java:835)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.store(IgniteH2Indexing.java:416)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.store(GridQueryProcessor.java:2548)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.store(GridCacheQueryManager.java:418)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.finishUpdate(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:2839)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.invoke0(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:1875)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:1844)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:471)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerUpdate(GridCacheMapEntry.java:2262)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateSingle(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2541)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.update(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2001)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1832)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1687)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.processNearAtomicUpdateRequest(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:3154)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$400(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:153)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:294)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:289)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1150)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:591)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:392)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:318)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:109)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:308)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1727)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1334)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4800(GridIoManager.java:158)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$8.execute(GridIoManager.java:1218)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:54)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.StripedExecutor$Stripe.body(StripedExecutor.java:567)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Below is the configuration which we used to deploy the Ignite on Azure

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-04-21T10:50:53Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app: ignite
  name: ignite-service
  namespace: ignite
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 10.0.65.116
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.0.65.116
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: rest
    nodePort: 32693
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: thinclients
    nodePort: 32087
    port: 10800
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 10800
  selector:
    app: ignite
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Service account creation

```
kubectl create sa ignite -n ignite
```

cluster-role.yaml

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: ignite
  namespace: ignite
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources: # Here are the resources you can access
  - pods
  - endpoints
  verbs: # That is what you can do with them
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ignite 
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: ignite 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ignite
  namespace: ignite
```

configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  node-configuration.xml: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<beans xmlns=\"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans\"\r\n
    \      xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\r\n       xsi:schemaLocation=\"\r\n
    \       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans\r\n        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd\">\r\n\r\n
    \   <bean class=\"org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration\">\r\n        <property
    name=\"peerClassLoadingEnabled\" value=\"true\"/>\r\n        <property name=\"discoverySpi\">\r\n
    \           <bean class=\"org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi\">\r\n
    \               <property name=\"ipFinder\">\r\n                    <bean class=\"org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder\">\r\n
    \                       <property name=\"namespace\" value=\"ignite\"/>\r\n                        <property
    name=\"serviceName\" value=\"ignite-service\"/>\r\n                    </bean>\r\n
    \               </property>\r\n            </bean>\r\n        </property>\r\n
    \   </bean>\r\n</beans>\r\n"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ignite-config
  namespace: ignite
```

deployment.yaml

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ignite-cluster
  namespace: ignite
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignite
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: ignite
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: OPTION_LIBS
          value: ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http,ignite-geospatial
        - name: CONFIG_URI
          value: file:///ignite/config/node-configuration.xml
        image: gridgain/community:8.8.27
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: ignite-node
        ports:
        - containerPort: 47100
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 47500
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 49112
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 10800
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /ignite/config
          name: config-vol
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: ignite
      serviceAccountName: ignite
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 100000
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: ignite-config
        name: config-vol
```

could you please check this once and let me know if anything is missing

successful cache initialization

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient information to debug fully, but it looks like it's having difficulty parsing the value of a geometry column. One or more values include invalid data.

Comment: Hi @Stephen Darlington, could you please tell me what info do you need

Comment: What values are you inserting into the geometry column?